# Email to 365 group using graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, email-client

Up to yesterday, sending email to a 365 group using graph api, sent the same email to all the members of the group.

Now, there is no error but no emails arrive.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: https://portal.office.com/servicestatus or https://status.cloud.microsoft/ showing errors?

Comment: Also have you tried sending email to that group outside of the API first to make sure its not the group?

Comment: No errors and no luck with regular email. I also tried a different 365 group.